# Eccentricity Vector in Java not accurate as orbit moves along

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

I am writing a small libgdx program in java that was inspired by Kerbal Space Program and I am now writing the class that controls objects that will have forces acted on them. Each of these objects have a velocity vector that is changed by a forces vector.

The program runs around 60 frames per second and every frame the calculations done on the force to change velocity are done 1000 times. ( I have played with this number a lot however). Right now the program is incredibly simple and the only force that is exerted and calculated every iteration is from the planet.

```
 forcedub = ((gravConstanat*parentBody.getMass())/Math.pow(loc.distance(parentBody.getLoc()),2));
 force = new Point2D(((-1)*forcedub*Math.cos(a)),((-1)*forcedub*Math.sin(a)));
```

This changes the velocity sightly, the position is adjusted and the loop continues. The process works very well and seems stable. I haven't run it for days on end, but the orbit even at relatively high eccentricities seems stable. UNFORTUNATELY I need to be able to speed this process up so it doesn't take 2 days real time to get to the moon. So I needed a system that puts the orbit "on rails" and doesn't need to recalculate the forces each iterations. Once the multiplier value there gets set too high the orbit falls apart.

Good news is I already have this system in place, I just can't switch between the two.

I need a few values from the orbit to do this in my system. (I know some values are a bit redundant but it is what it is).

- The semi major axis
- the semi minor axis
- the eccentricity vector
- eccentricity
- true anomaly
- focus information.

To cut to the chase, the biggest issue is the eccentricity vector / eccentricity. My 'bake' function is the one that attempts to compute the values from the state vectors of the orbit every iteration and the value of the eccentricity varies drastically where it should stay the same in a standard orbit.The direction the vector is all over the place as well.

I have hard coded a single object that should have an eccentricity of about .62 and the eccentricity vector should point to pi, but the value wanders between .25 and .88 and the direction wanders between pi and pi / 3 ish.

Here are two versions of how to get the eccvecc from the state vectors, and I have tried them both. They both give the exact same results:

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37331/why-does-the-eccentricity-vector-equation-always-equal-1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector

```
public void bake(){
    double velSq = Math.pow(vel.distance(0,0),2);
    double r = loc.distance(parentBody.getLoc());
    double gm = gravConstanat*parentBody.getMass();

    Point2D posr = new Point2D(loc.getX()-parentBody.getX(), loc.getY()-parentBody.getY());

    Point2D calc1 = posr.scale((velSq/gm));
    Point2D calc2 = vel.scale((dotProd(posr,vel)/gm));
    Point2D calc3 = posr.scale(1/r);

    Point2D eccVecc = (calc1.minus(calc2)).minus(calc3);

    ecc = eccVecc.distance(0,0);

    w = Math.toRadians(90)-(Math.atan2(eccVecc.x(),eccVecc.y()));

    semiA = (gm*r)/(2*gm - r*velSq);
    semiB = semiA*(Math.sqrt((1-Math.pow(ecc,2))));
    focus = findFocus(semiA,semiB);

    System.out.println("ecc  " + ecc + " W " + w + " SEMI A " + semiA);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is the entire class: 
**initial distance is about 900,000 to the left of the parent body
**parent mass is 5.3*Math.pow(10,22)

```
public class Klobject {

    String name;
    TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    Sprite sprite;
    Cbody parentBody;
    Point2D loc;
    Point2D vel;
    public boolean acceleration;

    double MULTIPLIER;
    static double gravConstanat = 6.67*Math.pow(10,-11);

    double semiA, semiB, ecc, w;

    protected double t;
    protected double mass;
    protected double rotateRate;
    protected double focus;

    public Klobject(Cbody cb){

        mass = 1;
        MULTIPLIER = 1;
        rotateRate = 0;
        parentBody = cb;
        acceleration = false;
        cb.addKlob(this);

        loc = new Point2D((parentBody.getX() - 900_000f ),
                (parentBody.getY()));

        vel = new Point2D(0,2526.733);

        sprite = textureAtlas.createSprite(name);
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
        bake();
    }


    public void update(float dt){

        oneXupdate(dt);
        bake();

    }

    private void oneXupdate(float dt){

        int timesLooped = 1000;

        double a;
        double forcedub;
        Point2D force;
        Point2D velout;
        double dx;
        double dy;
        dt = dt/timesLooped;

        for (int i = 0; i < timesLooped; i++){

            velout = vel.scale(MULTIPLIER);

            dx =  (dt*velout.getX());
            dy =  (dt*velout.getY());

            loc = new Point2D(loc.getX()+dx, loc.getY()+dy);

            a = Math.atan2(loc.getX()-parentBody.getX(), loc.getY()-parentBody.getY());
            a = Math.toRadians(90)-a;

            forcedub = ((gravConstanat*parentBody.getMass())/Math.pow(loc.distance(parentBody.getLoc()),2));
            force = new Point2D(((-1)*forcedub*Math.cos(a)),((-1)*forcedub*Math.sin(a)));


            force = force.scale(MULTIPLIER*MULTIPLIER);

            velout = velout.plus(new Point2D(force.getX()*dt,force.getY()*dt));

            vel = velout.scale(1/MULTIPLIER);


        }

    }


    public void bake(){
        double velSq = Math.pow(vel.distance(0,0),2);
        double r = loc.distance(parentBody.getLoc());
        double gm = gravConstanat*parentBody.getMass();

        Point2D posr = new Point2D(loc.getX()-parentBody.getX(), loc.getY()-parentBody.getY());

        Point2D calc1 = posr.scale((velSq/gm));
        Point2D calc2 = vel.scale((dotProd(posr,vel)/gm));
        Point2D calc3 = posr.scale(1/r);

        Point2D eccVecc = (calc1.minus(calc2)).minus(calc3);

        ecc = eccVecc.distance(0,0);

        w = Math.toRadians(90)-(Math.atan2(eccVecc.x(),eccVecc.y()));

        semiA = (gm*r)/(2*gm - r*velSq);
        semiB = semiA*(Math.sqrt((1-Math.pow(ecc,2))));
        focus = findFocus(semiA,semiB);

        System.out.println("ecc  " + ecc + " W " + w + " SEMI A " + semiA);
        System.out.println();


    }

    public double findFocus(double a, double b){
        return Math.sqrt(a*a - b*b);
    }

    public double getX(){
        return loc.getX();
    }
    public double getY(){
        return loc.getY();
    }
    public void setRotateRate(double rr){rotateRate = rr;}
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public Sprite getSprite(){
        return sprite;
    }
    public void setMultiplier(double mult){
        MULTIPLIER = mult;
    }
    public Point2D getLoc(){
        return loc;
    }
    public void setLoc(Point2D newLoc){
        loc = newLoc;
    }

    public double dotProd(Point2D a, Point2D b){
        return a.x()*b.x() + a.y()+b.y();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe double isn't the best datatype for exact floating-point operations... Have you tried BigDecimal?

Comment: @Nicktar If he's already having performance issues, that won't help it... use doubles and if you're having numerical stability problems perhaps you're doing something wrong. See [this article](https://gafferongames.com/post/integration_basics/) on numerical integration methods, it might help you.

Comment: Well slow but correct results might be more desireable than fast random numbers...